# Yii : Getting id after createCommand execute query

Tags: php, sql, yii

In active record, I usually just get

```
$model->id,
```

after

```
executing $model->save();
```

But how about createCommand? how do I get the id (pk) of the inserted row?

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->query();
```

I tried:
    $id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertedID();

but it asks for sequence name. error. How do I do the active record counter part? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go with `execute()` instead of `query()`

```
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

then you can use

```
 $id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

to get the Id of the newly inserted record.

You can read more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19153-last-inserted-id/).

Answer (score -1):

Insert row need execute

try:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute()
```

Comment: And then what do you do?